# How can I convert a string of object literals to an array of objects in JS?

Tags: javascript, json

I am having trouble converting the following string to an array of objects. I have tried varying combinations of json parse and stringify to no avail. Here's the code:

```
'{"lat": 51.25869, "lng": -0.55731},{"lat": 51.17095, "lng": -0.79179},{"lat": 51.07819, "lng": -0.72810},{"lat": 51.11948, "lng": -0.46185},'
```

I need it to be like this:

```
[
    {lat: 51.28876, lng: -0.50718},
    {lat: 51.18774, lng: -0.84672},
    {lat: 51.00566, lng: -0.78475},
    {lat: 51.08973, lng: -0.46529}
];
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you could just remove the trailing comma then add braces to get a perfectly valid JSON:

```
var json = "[" + myString.replace(/,$/, "") + "]";
var arr = JSON.parse(json);
```